# How to pass a mysqli object to a class constructor

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a user class and using the class to handle the login, but from some reason my user class constructor is reading my mysqli object as a string

Here's my code

Class.php

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class user{ 
    protected $email;
    protected $password; 
    private $db;
    protected $user;

    function __construct(mysqli $db, $email, $password){
        $this -> $db = $db;
        $this -> $email = $email;
        $this -> $password = $password;
    }

    protected function check(){
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =?';
        $handler = $this -> $db -> prepare($query);
        $handler -> execute(array($this->email));
        if($handler -> num_rows() > 0){
            $user = $handler -> fetch();
            $submitpassword = ($this -> $password);
            if ($submitpassword == $user['password']) {
                return $user;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function login(){
        $user = $this->check();
        if ($user) {
            $this->_user = $user; // store it so it can be accessed later
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
            return $user['id'];
        }
        return false;
    }

public function getUser(){
    return $this->_user;
}

}

?>
```

mysql.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo 'Page not found';
    exit();
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "imagesite";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php

include 'mysql.php';
include 'class.php';

// username and password sent from form 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['password']; 

$user = new user($conn, $email, $pass);
$id = $user -> login();
if ($id) {
    echo 'Logged it as user id: '.$user_id;
}else{
    echo 'did not work';
}


?>
```

It gives me this error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\class.php on line 13

I'm pulling my hair out with this, any ideas?

Comment: $this -> $db = $db on class.php

Comment: Use print_r($conn); in checklogin.php and tell output to me

Comment: mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.17 [server_version] => 50617 [stat] => Uptime: 3975 Threads: 1 Questions: 7 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 67 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 60 Queries per second avg: 0.001 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 6 [warning_count] => 0)

Comment: _$this ->$db = $db;_ should be: _$this->db = $db;_  note the  ->db rather than  ->$db.

Answer (score 1):

To use instance properties you don't need dollar sign. Simply change

```
function __construct(mysqli $db, $email, $password){
    $this -> $db = $db;
    $this -> $email = $email;
    $this -> $password = $password;
}
```

to this:

```
function __construct(mysqli $db, $email, $password){
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->password = $password;
}
```